# React- too many renders

Tags: reactjs

this code:

```
const TooMany = () => {
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

    const foo = (param) => {
        console.log("Called twice")
        return param;
    }

    let bar = foo(1);

    return (
        <div>
            TEST
        </div>
    )
}
```

runs `foo` twice. Why? My guess was that the second one is triggered by `useState` but when I created another `useState` it did not increase amount of the `foo` calls. So I am confused...

Comment: I would use `foo(1)` function call in `useEffect` hook instead.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with you code, at least obviously. If you created the application with `create-react-app` it is likely using [Strict Mode](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html). In development mode only there will be additional renders to attempt to highlight potential issues in your application. This will not happen in production mode.

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60825649/why-my-simple-react-component-print-console-twice/60825885#60825885

its because of React.StrictMode

Comment: As commented per others, this is due to strict mode. See this discussion on github https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/15074

Answer (score -1):

In React js Render method called every property change but not every other method, like as componentDidmount, WillMount, etc. in update React use React Hooks with the functional component. just one function use to solve it "useEffect" here the snippet or visite the link [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/small-voice-b4ymi?file=/src/App.js:0-49)

```html
const TooMany = () => {
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

    const foo = (param) => {
        console.log("Called twice")
        return param;
    }

    useEffect(()=>{
       let bar = foo(1);
    },[])

    return (
        <div>
            TEST
        </div>
    )
}
```