# console.log() statement being called twice in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My code is as follows:

```
//fetch tasks from server
      const fetchTasks=()=>{
    
        const fTask = async ()=>{
          const res = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/tasks')
          const data = await res.json()
    
          console.log("data", data)     
        }
    
        fTask()
    
      }
    
      fetchTasks()
```

I was expecting the data to be logged into the console only once, but for some reason, it is being logged twice. I tried debugger, but it too did not help..
thank you in advance..

Comment: Do you have [`Strict Mode`](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html) enabled?

Comment: @pilchard Yes, it is enabled... However, no warnings as such in the console...

Comment: Well that is your answer then, from the docs: 'Strict mode can’t automatically detect side effects for you, but it can help you spot them by making them a little more deterministic. **This is done by intentionally double-invoking the following functions**...'

Comment: @pilchard - disabling the strict mode helped, thanks a ton!

Comment: But... they said why in their comment?

Comment: see: [Why my simple react component print console twice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60825649/why-my-simple-react-component-print-console-twice) and [setTimeout callback called twice in React functional component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65765897/settimeout-callback-called-twice-in-react-functional-component)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Remove strict mode or turn it into <> </> fragments shortcut

do this instead

```
const fetchTasks= async ()=>{
      const res = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/tasks')
      const data = res.json()

      console.log("data", data)  
  }

  fetchTasks()
```